# How to add document to the next iteration of continuous crawl

Tags: 2013, search, crawl

Is there any way to add document to recrawl on the next iteration of continuous crawl?

It seems that `CrawlLog` API adds document to the next iteration of incremental crawl.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() => {
    var searchServiceApplication = //Assume that there are only one SSA on the farm
        SearchService.Service.SearchServiceApplications.FirstOrDefault();

    // Path should be for default Zone (because SSA crawl from Default Zone)
    path = ConvertToDefaultZoneUrl(path.TrimEnd('/'));

    var crawlLog = new CrawlLog(searchServiceApplication);
    var result = crawlLog.RecrawlDocument(path);

    if (result)
         Log.Trace("Document successfully added to recrawl queue '{0}'", path);
    else Log.Error("Document does not found '{0}'", path);
});
```

Is possible to update some field like `vti_searchversion` or another and does not change `Modified` / `Modified By` properties to force re-crawl of the document asap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand `item.Update()` is enough to add document to the next iteration of continuous crawl. In order to leave modified date unchanged we can use [this trick](https://sergeytihon.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/how-to-change-splistitem-created-or-modified-date/) (SharePoint allows to set arbitrary values in "Modified" & "Editor" fields)

It seems that following code is also works:

```
public static void ReCrawlDocument(string path)
{
    using (var site = new SPSite(path))
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        var pos = path.IndexOf("/", 8, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        var serverRelativeUrl = path.Substring(pos);
        var item = web.GetListItem(serverRelativeUrl);

        // Changing "vti_searchversion" may not be necessary
        var searchVersionPropertyName = "vti_searchversion";
        if (!item.Properties.ContainsKey(searchVersionPropertyName))
        {
            item.Properties.Add(searchVersionPropertyName, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            var versionObj = item.Properties[searchVersionPropertyName];
            var version = versionObj as int? ?? 0;
            item.Properties[searchVersionPropertyName] = (version + 1);
        }

        // These lines will help to not update modified date and editor fields
        item["Modified"] = item["Modified"];
        item["Editor"] = item["Editor"];

        var allowUnsafeUpdates = web.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        item.Update();
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUnsafeUpdates;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set **vti_searchversion** on a web, library or folder, not per item. Not ideal, but not too bad.

There's some code over at https://sebastian.expert/force-web-whole-list-library-re-crawled-search-sharepoint-2013-using-api/ you can use. Or my re-crawl scripts at https://github.com/wobba/SPO-Trigger-Reindex.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the document from the index, it should be picked up again on the next continuous crawl. Instructions to do it through the UI are available at: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219587.aspx.

I think you should might be able to achieve the same thing with the RemoveDocumentFromSearchResults() method on the crawl log object, but I'm not sure if that's creating a persistent block of the item from the search results, or just removing the item from the current index so that it can be added again.